# jQuery - Addition within .each() sum loop causing issue

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write an equation within a sum loop and everything works fine by the use of an addition sign `+`, which I'm assuming is confusing the incrementing of the sum loop. The value should be `56` for the equation but actual output is a string of `095959595`.

[JFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/darcyvoutt/e27hh6L3/)

The code looks like this:

```
$(function () {
    var feature = $('.product');
    var supplier = $('#supplier').val();

    var costCurve = $('#productCostCurve').val();
    var baseCost = $('#baseComponentCost').val();

    var unitCost = 0;

    $.each(feature, function () {
        unitCost += (costCurve * parseFloat($(this).val()) * baseCost * supplier) + baseCost;
    });

    $('#product-cost').html(unitCost);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `baseCost`, it is a string value so a string concatenation is done

```js
$(function() {
  var feature = $('.product');
  var supplier = $('#supplier').val();

  var costCurve = $('#productCostCurve').val();
    //use a unary plus or parseFloat to convert this to a numeric value
  var baseCost = +$('#baseComponentCost').val();

  var unitCost = 0;

  $.each(feature, function() {
    unitCost += (costCurve * parseFloat($(this).val()) * baseCost * supplier) + baseCost;
  });

  $('#product-cost').html(unitCost);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="productCostCurve" value="0.5" />
<input type="text" id="baseComponentCost" value="5" />
<input type="text" class="product" value="4" />
<input type="text" class="product" value="4" />
<input type="text" class="product" value="4" />
<input type="text" class="product" value="4" />
<input type="text" id="supplier" value="0.9" />
<div id="product-cost"></div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `supplier` and the `costCurve` have the same issue?

Comment: @nem it is used in a multiplication operation which is numeric specific so the conversion will be done automatically... the `+` operator is used as addition and string concatenation operator